# How to enable Notes to uncompress gzip files when doing preview in webbrowser

Tags: lotus-domino, gzip, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a bunch of gzipped javascript files that are added to resources\files in a Notesdatabase.  when I view these files on the server, Domino seem to unzip them and show them correct in the webbrowser. but when I view them using preview in webbrowser the files are not unzipped.

is there any notes.ini pararmeter I can use on the client to make this work also when doing preview in webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

There are .ini settings on the server that govern how gzip files are handled but there aren't any I'm aware of for the client/designer. To my knowledge, the only objects you can preview in a web browser from designer are forms, views, folders, xpages and pages. Resources can't be previewed. Can you be more specific about what actions you're taking?

Note: this should have been a comment but my karma isn't high enough yet to allow for that. Please be kind before down voting.